# Core Data fetch inconsistencies

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm working with a very small sample project that can be [downloaded from here](https://github.com/acburk/CoreData-Tutorial-1/zipball/Tutorial3). What I'm trying to do is debug why fetching is taking so long in my own project, but I've used this project as a sort of benchmark. I've enabled `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`in my scheme so I can see what commands are being sent to the SQLite store with my fetches.

First, in the AppDelegate, I just wrap the first part (where the bank is being created) in a for loop to create 1000 objects. Them comment out the fetch request from the AppDelegate.

Then, in the FBCFMasterViewController, there is a fetch request there. Upon running the app after saving the 1000 items, and fetching them to an NSFetchedResultsController, you'll see thousands of output lines similar to these:

```
2012-06-23 09:16:30.374 FailedBankCD[90166:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
2012-06-23 09:16:30.375 FailedBankCD[90166:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0009s for 1 rows.
2012-06-23 09:16:30.375 FailedBankCD[90166:fb03] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0xc3e9060 <x-coredata://60E5B64A-83AB-4E6A-BEAD-5FFF50DB7F66/FailedBankDetails/p823>
2012-06-23 09:16:30.376 FailedBankCD[90166:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCLOSEDATE, t0.ZUPDATEDATE, t0.ZZIP, t0.ZINFO FROM ZFAILEDBANKDETAILS t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?
```

What I'm guessing that's from is that the sortDescriptor is initialized with key details.closeDate, which is a relationship, so as it sorts by that property, it has to fetch fault each object in, causing thousands of lines of output to appear.

So I changed the sortDescriptor to sort on the property `city` instead, and this time when I run, I get the following output:

```
2012-06-23 08:53:04.924 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZFAILEDBANKINFO t0 ORDER BY t0.ZCITY DESC
2012-06-23 08:53:04.929 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0049s
2012-06-23 08:53:04.930 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0059s for 1009 rows.
2012-06-23 08:53:04.936 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCITY, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSTATE, t0.ZDETAILS FROM ZFAILEDBANKINFO t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZCITY DESC LIMIT 10
2012-06-23 08:53:04.938 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0013s
2012-06-23 08:53:04.939 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCLOSEDATE, t0.ZUPDATEDATE, t0.ZZIP, t0.ZINFO FROM ZFAILEDBANKDETAILS t0 WHERE  t0.ZINFO IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  
2012-06-23 08:53:04.971 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0318s
2012-06-23 08:53:04.972 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0326s for 10 rows.
2012-06-23 08:53:04.973 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: Prefetching with key 'details'.  Got 10 rows.
2012-06-23 08:53:04.974 FailedBankCD[89564:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0372s for 10 rows.
```

I don't get repeating thousands of lines of output anymore, and this appears to be the expected output. However, if I run again, without even modifying anything, I again get thousands of lines of output similar to the following:

```
2012-06-23 09:19:31.263 FailedBankCD[90216:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0006s
2012-06-23 09:19:31.264 FailedBankCD[90216:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0010s for 20 rows.
2012-06-23 09:19:31.264 FailedBankCD[90216:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCITY, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSTATE, t0.ZDETAILS FROM ZFAILEDBANKINFO t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZCITY DESC LIMIT 20
```

This is odd behavior, no? Can anyone quickly replicate this and explain what's going on, and why I'm getting thousands of lines of output?

Comment: Is the result the same? I would not be worried about Core Data translates queries under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`close_date` and `city` aren't indexed, that's explain the thousands of queries, and probably low performance. For the difference between runs, I would bet on the cache you are using :

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
```